# Rendering tkinter create_text with angle

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Is there a way to improve the rendering of texts in Tkinter? Or should I use another library?

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(window,width=200, height=200, bg='blue')
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_text(100, 100, text="1234567890", fill="white", font=('Arial', 8, 'bold'),angle=3)
window.mainloop()
```

is returning the picture below, where numbers are not having the same spacing and not being on the same line

[image: tkinter text rendering]

Thanks

Comment: Bigger font size looks smoother, [reply.it](https://repl.it/repls/OutrageousSeagreenSphere)